# define integer array fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I am a newbie in Fortran.
Can any1 tell me how to define an integer array in prior.
E.g.
I want to define an array with no.of days in 12 months.
like...

```
integer,allocatable(12,1) :: days

days=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
```

Is this syntax correct? If not, please let me know the correct one.

Thanks
Praveen

Answer (score 2):

If you want a dynamically allocated array, try the following:

```
program arraytest
  implicit none
  integer, allocatable :: a(:)

  allocate(a(12))
  a = (/31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31/)
  print *, a
end program arraytest
```

Answer (score 1):

`integer, dimension(12) :: a = (/ 31, 28, 31, 30, ... /)`

for "static" array. the `[ ]` instead of `(/ /)` is correct for Fortran 2003 and later; all the compilers I know allow that syntax even though they do not implement fully F2003. For dynamic array:

```
integer, dimension(:) :: a
! ...
allocate(a(12))
a = (/ .... /)
! ...
deallocate(a)
```

is an option too.

Answer (score 0):

In FORTRAN 77, I'd say

```
  INTEGER DAYS(12) / 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 /
```

That's declaration and initialization in one.

If you want, you can also separate the two:

```
  INTEGER DAYS(12)
  DATA DAYS / 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 /
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably doesn't need to be allocatable, does it, since it's just a constant array:

```
INTEGER :: a(12) = (/ 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 /)
```